# How to do sorting with hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have an array of objects of hash value and need to sort by `title` in  ASC/DESC

```
@ass_list = [{id:1,title:b},{id:2,title:a},{id:3,title:c}]
```

I want to sort by the `title` of each object, and tried:

```
@Q_title = @ass_list.sort_by {|k| k[:title]}
```

When i do code for shorting object for title ,it should give me result like below

```
@ass_list = [{id:2,title:a},{id:1,title:b},{id:3,title:c}]
```

However, it does not work.

Comment: not its not working i want object =[a,b,c]

Comment: @P_M   what are `a, b, c` ?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking? Do you want to sort it by the title or get all the title values and then sort them?

Comment: please check my question again

Comment: @P_M I've added an answer below, I think this is what you want.

Comment: @RaVeN I think you've helped clarify things. I believe OP wants to end up with the an array of title values in order i.e. `[a, b, c]`.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

For reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort

ASC:

```
@ass_list.sort do |x, y|
  x[:title] <=> y[:title]
end
```

DESC:

```
@ass_list.sort do |x, y|
  y[:title] <=> x[:title]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you require:

```
@Q_title = @ass_list.sort_by { |h| h[:title] }.map {|h| h[:title] } #=> [a, b, c]
```

Note: the values of `a`, `b` and `c` are returned in the array.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `@ass_list.map {|h| h[:title] }.sort`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes it is :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I guess, my excuse (not a very good one)... I was modifying the OP's initial attempt. But yeah, I should have spotted the even simpler version you have pointed out- thanks